# reusing test suites with multiple implementations?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I'm testing with nUnit.  I have a suite of tests that run against my IFoo interface; the Test Fixture Setup determines which IFoo implementation to load and test.

I'm trying to figure out how to run the same suite against a list of IFoo implementaions, but don't see any way to test all implementations without manually modifying the Setup.

Has anyone tackled this problem?

Comment: Great solutions.  I'd never have thought of inheriting unit tests.  And never realized nUnit would also test base class methods.

Answer (score 13):

Create a base test class that contains tests shared between IFoo implementations like this:

```
// note the absence of the TestFixture attribute
public abstract class TestIFooBase
{
   protected IFoo Foo { get; set; }

   [SetUp]
   public abstract void SetUp();

   // all shared tests below    

   [Test]
   public void ItWorks()
   {
      Assert.IsTrue(Foo.ItWorks());
   }
}
```

Now create a very small derived class for each implementation you want to test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestBarAsIFoo : TestIFooBase
{
   public override void SetUp()
   {
      this.Foo = new Bar();
   }
}
```

**edit**: Apparently NUnit also has support for [parameterized test fixtures](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5), even generic test fixtures with parameter types are supported. Example from the linked documentation:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ArrayList))]
[TestFixture(typeof(List<int>))]
public class IList_Tests<TList> where TList : IList, new()
{
  private IList list;

  [SetUp]
  public void CreateList()
  {
    this.list = new TList();
  }

  [Test]
  public void CanAddToList()
  {
    list.Add(1); list.Add(2); list.Add(3);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, list.Count);
  }
}
```

This example is a bit simplistic because it has the `new()` constraint for the types. But you could also use `Activator.CreateInstance` and pass the constructor arguments for your `IFoo` implementations from the `TestFixture` attributes.

Comment: Parameterized Test Fixtures seriously cool! Just added it to test two implementations, great thing is being able to see time it takes for each implementation to do its stuff. + 1

Answer (score 1):

One of several ways to accomplish this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

public class Bar : IFoo
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Bar";  // will fail
    }
}

public abstract class TestBase
{
    protected abstract IFoo GetFoo();

    [Test]
    public void GetName_Returns_Foo()
    {
        IFoo foo = GetFoo();
        Assert.That(foo.GetName(), Is.EqualTo("Foo"));
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class FooTests : TestBase
{
    protected override IFoo GetFoo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class BarTests : TestBase
{
    protected override IFoo GetFoo()
    {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```